# C# - How do i get a slash in DATETIME, with System.Globalization.CultureInfo

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I want a date format in danish in this format

```
"Tor. 27/6"
```

Tor is short for torsdag, meaning thursday in danish

I have this code

```
string formatted = datetime.ToString("ddd. dd/MM", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK"));
```

It's returning

```
"To. 27-6"
```

so it's using a dash and ignoring the slash.
How do i force it to use slash while still using cultureinfo danish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `/` character has the specific meaning of ["culture specific date separator"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator) in custom date/time format strings.

If you want a literal `/`, you need to quote it in the pattern:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
string formatted = datetime.ToString("ddd. dd'/'MM", culture);
```

Output on my machine:

```
to. 27/06
```

It's using "06" instead of "6" because you've used `MM` in your format string - if you don't want zero padding for the day and month numbers, use `"ddd. d'/'M"` as the format string. That doesn't help the "to" become "Tor", admittedly. If you want that, you'd need to modify the culture's abbreviated day-of-week values.

Comment: " If you want that, you'd need to modify the culture's abbreviated day-of-week values.", how, can you give example?

Comment: @HansPreutz: Not in comments, no. I suggest you ask a new question with all the relevant details. (I'm interested that you get "To." when I get "to." though...)

Comment: @Cid: The length would vary based on the day and month number. It's not clear why you expect Hans to need exactly 10 characters. (I can't see that requirement anywhere.) I *expect* Hans just always wants 3 character day names, which is much easier to sort out with a custom culture than manipulating the final result, IMO.

Comment: @Cid: Yes, but Hans already expressed a desire for it to *not* be a zero-padded month number. (I want a date format in danish in this format "Tor. 27/6")

Comment: @JonSkeet my bad, I didn't notice it in the question. that's definitely not a solution then

Comment: @JonSkeet, sorry my bad. I did in fact get "to." it was a copy paste error.

Answer (score 2):

surround the desired date seperator ('/' in this case) with single quote.

```
string formatted = datetime.ToString("ddd. dd'/'MM", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK"));
```

Comment: another solution : same like solution in VB6 // except add '@' in front of the string.

`string formatted = datetime.ToString(@"ddd. dd\/MM", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK"));`